# Devanagari Swar Characters

Tags: unicode, devanagari

I can see 2 types of characters on this page...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)

Group A:

```
 ऀ   ँ   ं   ः   ऺ   ऻ  ़   ा   ि   ी   ु   ू   ृ   ॄ   ॅ   ॆ   े   ै   ॉ   ॊ   ो   ौ   ्   ॎ   ॏ  ॑  ॒   ॕ   ॖ   ॗ   ॢ   ॣ
```

Group B:

```
ऽ   ऄ   अ   आ   इ   ई   उ   ऊ   ऋ   ऌ   ऍ   ऎ   ए   ऐ   ऑ   ऒ   ओ   औ   क   ख   ग   घ   ङ   च   छ   ज   झ   ञ   ट   ठ   ड   ढ   ण   त   थ   द   ध   न   ऩ   प   फ   ब   भ   म   य   र   ऱ   ल   ळ   ऴ   व   श   ष   स   ह   ॐ
```

I will like to know what the Group A is called. I am calling it Group A because all of these characters are having a circle in it. It is called "swar" characters?

Comment: Note: the circle indicates just that such characters are "combining characters" (and an example for where original character should be and how the character may be shows. But on Indian languages, ligatures may change completely the form (and it may depend on exact language/region and epoch of writing). ZWNJ/ZWJ may be used to override font ligatures. See https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch12.pdf for details.

Comment: Are ligatures used by any language other than Devanagari?

Comment: Yes. Latin script fonts have often ligatures in `ff`, `ffi`. Accented characters are seen as ligatures (e.g. on i you do not put the dot). Cursive scripts needs ligatures (Latin cursive, Arabic, etc.). New Korean is own type (very artificial scripts). German ß (eszet), and commercial & were ligatures (now considered characters). Arabic (and sigma in Greek) has positional "ligatures" (it depends if it is initial, final, middle, alone). Asian scripts (especially Indian and South East Asian) are more extreme on ligatures (and so the heavier users of ZWNJ/ZWJ) to correct font automatic rules.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In that case why are ligatures named as "Spacing Mark" on this page? https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Mc

Comment: No. You may see some information in the Unicode document. But ligatures (and in general how to display characters) are outside Unicode scope. That is a task of fonts (they have many tables, various on how to select the right glyph depending of nearby characters. In Indian scripts, ligatures depends on exact language, region and epoch (there are some general ligatures, but good typesettings must care of specific languages. Unicode standard has some indication but as written text, not in databases. Some utilities can extract data from good fonts (in case you want to know more)

Comment: The context of this question is here... https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142437

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the bug. Ligatures change only the "visual" part (but not the order of chars in a string, which are usually "logical/pronunciation order". So I do not understand why auto-correction will change the order (or it may uses data from a later step (in pango/harfbuzz, I think you use pango/harbuzz for find "display order", choosing glyph and where to put glyphs)). Or there is an old work-around, for the pre-pango times?